# How to creat a big matrix in MATLAB and fill it gradually in a loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimension

I want to create a 36*45 dimensional martrix in MATLAB, but the columns will be filled in a loop. At the beginning I just have  a matrix of 36*1 as the initial values to be filled in the first column and gradually by running the loop the rest of columns will be filled. It is important to know that the size of big matrix (36*45) should be known from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I fill the matrix in backwards. This prevents the need for a separate allocation line, and sometimes it's quite a bit simpler. (e.g. when filling in an array of structures with indeterminate fields)

That looks like this:

```
for ix = numColumns:-1:1
    results(:,ix) = <function generating results>;  %No pre-allocation required
end
```

---

*Unrelated but interesting side comment below*

For some rather bizarre reasons, I think that this is actually somewhat faster than a `zeros()` call for very large matrices. You can see this by comparing the following:

```
tic; for ix=1:1000; x = zeros(1000); end; toc
%1.18 second on my current computer

tic; for ix=1:1000; clear('y'); y(1000,1000)=0; end; toc
%0.032 seconds on my current computer
```

I've seen a good description of the cause of this somewhere on Stackoverflow, but can't find it right now.

Comment: No its not. Preallocating is *always* faster.

Comment: Iterating backwards does a full allocation in the first time through the loop. This gains all the advantages of pre-allocation. The bizarre speed-up is a second-order effect, caused because `x=zeros(n)` is noticeably slower than `x(n,n)=0`, for large values of `n`.

Comment: humm It may be. However, it also my be version specific.

Comment: I have not seen any version differences in the backwards loop construct going back to at least v6. The backwards loop will always force a full memory allocation in the first loop. I think that Matlab does some specific memory optimization for the `for ix = 1:n` design pattern, which would be lost. However I think that only matters for very large values of `n`, where the `1:n` vector consumes a large fraction of available memory.

Comment: Its 0.32 vs 0.02 in MATLAB R2014b. I believe that in 2016a this memory-time performances have been incredibly improved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn a bit about MATLAB basics. I suggest you do that. The code would look like:

```
A=zeros(36,45);

for ii=1:size(A,2);
   A(:,ii) = %here comes a 36x1 matrix
end
```

Learn about matrix indexing here: https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html?refresh=true

Comment: Just change A(:,1) to A(:,ii). I would do the edit myself but so complains about the edit being too short :)